# Using Firebase and Angular, how can I retrieve a key generated from another page?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a grocery list app that stores food ids inside a user's list. The name of this list is generated with a .push method that is fired once, when the user registers, and will always remain the same. I need to retrieve this value on other pages that edit the food attributes.

Here is my database structure:

```
"userlist" : {
  {
    "-L-i60DHuiX6jba6TZLt" : {
      "list" : {
        "-L-4FJ9EaFjtDT_7XO6c" : {
          "category" : "Beverages",
          "foodname" : "7Up",
          "state" : "on"
        },
        "-L-i4dIBkloIxZPtY3Ge" : {
          "category" : "bread",
          "foodname" : "toast",
          "state" : "on"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I retrieve the value of the first value shown, "-L-i60DHuiX6jba6TZLt"?

Comment: are you opposed to having a structure like this: userList/{uid}/list/{item_key} instead? or even better: grocery_lists/{uid}/{item_key} ?

Comment: @Vincent That's actually the structure I had previously. I'm switching it to this structure for sharing purposes so that multiple uids can access the same list.

Answer (score 0):

The push() method doesn't return the generated key, even though it's generated locally.

So in this scenario you should generate your own key which you can persist in your app, instead of using push().

```
// Generate new key (client side)
let newKey = ref.push().key();
```

Then instead of pushing to a list, you can just call set() or update() on a specific object ref (that doesn't exist yet).

```
ref(`/userlist/${newKey}`).set({ category: 'bread' });
```